# Expectation Value well defined if $\lim_{p\to 0} X = \infty$

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

I have a compact space $S\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a pdf $p$ over $S$. $p$ is not guaranteed to be greater than $0$. If I have a random variable $X$ that depends on $p$ such that for $p$ going to $0$ $X$ goes to infinity is it still correct to define the expected value of $X$ as the integral $\int_S pX$ ? Can you point me to a relevant manual or reference?

EDIT:
As an example if $S = [0,1]\times [0,1]$,  $X=-\log{p}$ and $\exists \epsilon,~ p(x,y) > \epsilon ~\forall x,y \in S$ then $\int_S pX$ is finite and well defined. Instead if $p(x,y) = 0$ for a subset of $S$ which has non zero measure, then the expectation value cannot be written as $\int_S pX$ because this is integral is not well defined.

What are then the conditions on $X$, $S$ and $p$ such that $\mathbb{E}_{\sim p}[X] = \int_S pX$?

Comment: Currently, there are two close votes indicating a lack of clarity. To summarize my own questions :  You require a "measure" on $S$ to integrate over it, so without specifying that measure there is a lacuna in the question. If I try to place $S$ in a traditional setting , say $S = [0,1]$ (with the "Lebesgue" measure) then it's likely that the usual definition of expectation already covers it, so I presume you are asking about "other" $S$. Once you put a measure in, you get a theory of integration corresponding to that measure and something like "$\int_S Xp$" makes sense.

Comment: S in my case is a the product of segments in $\mathbb{R}$ -  I hope now its clearer, my doubt is about the conditions on $X$ such that the integral is well defined

Comment: Oh, if it's a product of segments on $\mathbb R$ (I'm not fully sure what "product" means, but I'll take it to be a cartesian product of sets) then you really don't have a problem because $S$ is then a high-dimensional rectangle, and for such there is an obvious measure. However, I've now got a second concern : $X$ is just something fixed, when $p$ is fixed. So fixing $p$, fixing $X$, something like $\int_S pX$ can be made sense of with some effort. I don't quite see what "$X$ going to infinity" has to do with this just as yet, though.

Comment: I understand the confusion now. I am computing divergences and the integrand depends on $p$ and in many cases is not bound. I have given a specific example above. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for closing the question while I was editing it ...

Comment: Your example $X = -\log p$ does not make sense because it is not clear how that is a random variable (i.e., $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$). If it somehow is a random variable, its distribution function $F_X(x)=P[X\leq x]$ is unclear and there is no reason to believe its distribution has PDF $p$.

Comment: Hi @Michael I don't understand. if $p$ is a pdf $p:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ then a also $f(p(\dot)):\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ if $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}$, the question is what is the expectation value of $f(p)$ and when the integral $\int p ~f(p)$ exists and is the same as the expectation value. This happens every time one computes a divergence and approximates it as the average over the samples. The problem arise when the support of $p$ is not the entire space.

Comment: I am asking, because I could not find it myself, where I can find material about this. For example what are convergence conditions on $p$ and on $X$. What it means when the support of p is not the entire space etc.

Comment: If $p:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a joint PDF for a random vector $X=(X_1, ..., X_n)$, where each component $X_i$ is a measurable function $X_i:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,  then the expectation of $X$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ given by $$ E[X] = (E[X_1], ..., E[X_n]) = \int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} (x_1,...,x_n) p(x_1,...,x_n)dx_1....dx_n$$

Comment: Now if you want to use the PDF function $p$ itself, together with some function $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, to define some new random variable as a function of the old random vector $X$, call it $Y=f(p(X)) = f(p(X_1, ..., X_n))$, then (assuming measurability of $p$ and $f$) we have that  $Y$ is a random variable and its expectation is: $$E[Y] = \int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} f(p(x_1, ..., x_n))p(x_1, ..., x_n)dx_1\cdots dx_n$$

Comment: Thanks. So far everything is fine. In your example, the problem arise when the support of $p$ is not the entire space on which $X$ is defined and at the same time $f(0)$ is not defined and $\lim_{p\to 0}{f(p)} = \infty$

Comment: As an example lets say $X = (x_1, x_2) \in S$ with $S = [-1,1]\times[-1,1]$ and $p(x_1,x_2) = 1/3$ if $x_1 > 0$ or $x_2 > 0$  else $p(x_1, x_2) = 0$, consider $Y=-p\log{p}$. Clearly $\int_S p(x_1, x_2)Y(p(x_1, x_2))dx_1, dx_2$ is not defined. Clearly one needs the support of $p$ to be almost everywhere in $S$. And even if that is the case there are convergence conditions on that integral. I have the strong feeling that this is standard material on some statistics book, I just can't find anything.